# Am I having two different versions of NodeJS on my Mac?

Tags: node.js

I am new to NodeJS and have installed it through Homebrew. But when I run node --version and npm --version commands, they reports that I have old version, while Homebrew tell me that I have installed the latest version when I try the upgrade command. The result when I run these commands is demonstrated in the following picture. What does this means?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It kind of looks like you may have two different versions of node installed (by different means).  Is this the case?

If you don't, you may just need to close/reopen your shell for the new version to take effect, if the installer is comprehensive enough.  If that doesn't do the trick, you probably just need to update your environment variables to point to the new version.  This will require exporting [NODE_HOME in your bash profile](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/) (if you're using bash)

If you need to manage multiple versions of node/npm, I would consider using [Node Version Manager (nvm)](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Oh, it seems like that I have installed a different version in the past through pkg installer, it is shown through the package install histories. I'm going to uninstall these packages and see if it can help. Any advises else? I just want a single version by now.

Comment: I'd just remove the one you installed with pkg installer and then just point your environment variable to the one you installed with brew, or remove the brew-installed one and install an updated version with pkg installer.  Either way works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing Node.js version
First of all, let’s remove the existing Node.js version from your computer.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
brew uninstall --force node
```

Install NVM using Homebrew
Let’s install Node Version Manager (NVM). It will allow us to manage multiple active node.js versions.

```
brew install nvm
```

Install Node.js via NVM
You can now install a specific Node.js version or install a LTS (Long-term support version).

```
nvm install --lts
or

nvm install 12.7.0
```

Now you can switch between different Node.js versions using the following command.

```
nvm use 16
node -v
v16.17.0

nvm use 12
node -v
v12.7.0
```